# c++ convert vector of integers to an integer

Tags: c++, vector, converters

was searching the web for an easy guide and couldn't find one.

I build a converter from decimal to binary and have the 1's and 0's saved in a vector. I want now to turn that vector into one integer.
I found all kinds of ways (that I didn't really understand) to convert to string and than to integer, can that be avoided?
I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

here is my code:

c.hpp:

```
#ifndef C_HPP
#define C_HPP
#include <vector>


class Dualrechnung{
private:
    std::vector<int> vec;
    int z = 123456; //Eingegebene Zahl
    int t_z = z; //temp Zahl

public:
    Dualrechnung();
    ~Dualrechnung();
};

#endif
```

c.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include "c.hpp"
#include <iostream>


Dualrechnung::Dualrechnung()
{
    int b;
        for (int i=0; (t_z-(pow(2,i))) >= 0; i++) //finds biggest power of 2 in z
        {
            b= i;
        }
        t_z-=pow(2,b); //whats left after the biggest power 
        vec.push_back(1);
    for(int i = b; i > 0; --i) //checks for every power of 2 multiples smaller than b if they exist in z. if they are, saves 1 for that power in the vector and if not, saves 0.
    {
        b--;
        if((t_z-pow(2,b)) >= 0)
            {
                vec.push_back(1);
                t_z-=pow(2,b);
            }
        else{vec.push_back(0);}
    }

// here I'd like that integer with the information from the vector

    int bin; //binary value of z
        std::cout << z << " in Dual ist " << bin;

}


Dualrechnung::~Dualrechnung(){}
```

c_test.cpp:

```
#include "c.cpp"
#include <iostream>


int main(){

    Dualrechnung *d = new Dualrechnung();
    delete d;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not use pow() with integers.

Comment: "have the 1's and 0's saved in a vector" looks like yo just need `std::bitset`

Comment: Unrelated extension to @drescherjm 's comment: `pow` is designed for really nasty cases like e to the power of pi, and this can make using it for something relatively simple like 2 to the x grossly expensive. You are probably better off with simple multiplication, possibly in a loop, or bit shifting (`1 << n`).

Comment: How would such a loop look like? can you give me a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote smth like this for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> myNumInVect = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1};
    int myNumInInteger = 0;
    int baseOfMyNumInVector = 2;
    for (int i : myNumInVect) {
        myNumInInteger = myNumInInteger * baseOfMyNumInVector + i;
    }
    cout << myNumInInteger;
    return 0;
}
```

(output of this code is 25 as expected (11001(2)=25(10))

it uses [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method), so number of operation '*' = vector.size(). It's easy adaptable to others bases positional numeral systems vector (by changing the baseOfMyNumInVector).

-----------@edit-----------

I know you have it, but i want also to show you how easy can be done conversion dec2givenBase without any pow, or smth like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int myNumInInteger = 111;
    int baseOfMyNumInVector = 2;
    vector<int> myNumInVect;

    while (myNumInInteger > 0) { // using Horner Scheme for switching base
        myNumInVect.push_back(myNumInInteger % baseOfMyNumInVector);
        myNumInInteger /= baseOfMyNumInVector;
    }

    std::reverse(myNumInVect.begin(), myNumInVect.end()); // reverse (bcs there is no push_front() method in vector)

    if (myNumInVect.empty()) { // handling the 0 case
        myNumInVect.push_back(0);
    }

    for (auto digit : myNumInVect) { // write the result
        cout << digit;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot Mariusz that really helped.
I was wondering, what exactly is this (int i : vector) mean? is it inheritance? or a syntax just for for loops?

Comment: it means for each int i from vector.
In this case you can replace it by:
`for (int i = 0; i < myNumInVect.size(); ++i) {

        myNumInInteger = myNumInInteger * baseOfMyNumInVector + myNumInVect[i];
    }`

We can do for(type name : container) {} for all containers that we can iterate thought but care bcs for(type name : container) {} != for(type &name : container) {}

it's called "range based for" if you want to know more about it

Comment: *through ... 
[Here](https://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html) you have a good article about it, everything explained.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly you need to convert `int` to set of bits and vice versa. Just use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) which has constructor from `unsigned long` and method to convert it back (you can also convert it to/from string of 0 and 1s).

Comment: `std::bitset` does not have iterators.

Comment: If it did, would they not be **bit**erators?